# How to connect an AWS Load Balancer to nginx ingress controller with Kubernetes deployed on EC2 with kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, aws-elb

I have installed Kubernetes Cluster on AWS using kubeadm. I understand that it will not fall under AWS Deployment. I am trying to follow the baremetal fashion of installing Kubernetes.

Everything works fine for Nodeport, I want to know if I can connect an AWS Load Balancer to this setup, If yes, how?

I've thoroughly researched online and found this solution where in we can specify an external IP address to a service. But, Load Balancers do not have IP addresses.

I am using Nginx Ingress Controller, everything works fine on ClusterIP, how can I expose the application using AWS Load Balancer?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach to integrate aws-load-balancer with nginx-ingress-controller running in kubernetes cluster created/running on EC2

Step 1: Setup/Install "nginx-ingress-controller"

Step 2: Create a extra service to expose "nginx-ingress-controller" on fix ports with NodePort . See below screenshot highlighted in yellow

[image: nginx-ingress-controller external service as NodePort Kubernetes]

Extra service to expose "nginx-ingress-controller" externally will look like following if you installed "nginx-ingress-controller" in "kube-system" namespace using helm

[image: Helm list of nginx-ingress-controller]

[image: Extra Service to expose nginx-ingress-controller externally on NodePort]

Step 3: Go to [Load Balancers Section in EC2 from AWS Console](https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=ap-south-1#LoadBalancers:sort=loadBalancerName) ,

then Create Load Balancer, for Simplicity choose "Classic Load Balancer's Create Button"

[image: AWS Classic Load Balancer setup]

Setup Ports and Protocol configuration as Below

[image: AWS Classic load balancer Ports and Protocol Configuration]

Then Assign your Security group , Configure health check for instances,

Finally Add your cluster Instances from list , Add tags and finally review and click
create done.

Visit the LB's DNS Name , you will find your "nginx-ingress-controller" exposed.